# How to create a map of character and dynamic ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I want to create a hashmap defined as `HashMap<Character,ArrayList<String>>`.
What I am trying to do is to read a set of strings which I am reading into a list.
From this list I want to generate this hashmap.
So if strings are something like this

Andy,Aman,Rocky,Ravi,Nick etc.
Map should be like

```
A->[Andy,Aman]
R->[Rocky,Ravi]
N->Nick
```

What I have tried is something like this

```
ArrayList<String> xlist= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<Character,ArrayList<String>> h = new HashMap<Character,ArrayList<String>>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(String sin : list){
        Character x =sin.charAt(0);
        //System.out.println(sin.charAt(0));
        if(h.containsKey(x)){
            h.get(x).add(sin);
            //xlist.clear();
            //xlist = h.get(x);
            //xlist.add(sin);
            //h.put(x,xlist.clone());

        }
        else{
            xlist.clear();
            xlist.add(sin);
            h.put(x,xlist);

        }
    }
```

When I print the hashmap, I get this

```
{A=[Ravi, Rocky], R=[Ravi, Rocky], N=[Ravi, Rocky]}
```

I understand , that all the lists in values are being reflected from same copy of list, but I don't know , how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite the loop, you can just change your last line within the else block so you won't change content of map on every iteration:

```
h.put(x,new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sin)));
```

You can also do it using Java 8 Streams which makes it much shorter:

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.charAt(0)));
```

If you want to preserve the order of keys you can use it with LinkedHashMap:

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d->d.charAt(0), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, that was so stupid of me, its looking so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

`xlist` is always the same list, even after you've put it in your hashmap. Whenever you hit a new letter, you clear *every* list in your hashmap, and add the current word to every list, because they're all the same list.

I'd rewrite your loop as:

```
for(String sin : list){
    Character x =sin.charAt(0);
    if(!h.containsKey(x)){
        h.put(x, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    h.get(x).add(sin);
}
```

Comment: With Java 8, you can replace the whole loop body with `h.computeIfAbsent(sin.charAt(0), c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(sin);`

Comment: @Andrew Ruekert: Thanks Kamil, that was so stupid of me, its looking so obvious now.Much cleaner loop now.